# Wait before returning value iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tcp

I found some classes on the internet to establish a tcp connection. The link is in [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html). I want to customize a class and so far I am able to establish a connection send data and receive data which is great. Once I have created and imported the classes used by the first link that I provided I am able to establish a connection using the following method:

```
-(void) connectToServerUsingCFStream:(NSString *) urlStr portNo: (uint) portNo {

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                       (CFStringRef) urlStr, 
                                       portNo, 
                                       &readStream, 
                                       &writeStream);

    if (readStream && writeStream) {
        CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, 
                                kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, 
                                kCFBooleanTrue);
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, 
                                 kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, 
                                 kCFBooleanTrue);

        iStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
        [iStream retain];
        [iStream setDelegate:self];
        [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [iStream open];

        oStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
        [oStream retain];
        [oStream setDelegate:self];
        [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [oStream open];    

    }
}
```

Since I am going to use this class a lot on my application I am creating my own class and I want to create a `-(BOOL) connect{}`  method. I want to return yes is the connection is establish and no otherwise. The problem is that the way I am able to tell if I establish a connection is by creating a connection attempting to send data and then on the server side I have created a method that whenever I receive that I send a string back. If in the next 2 seconds I receive data I know that the connection was establish.

so in my connection method I want to wait 2 seconds and then return a value depending if the BOOL variable didReciveData = YES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a `NSOutputStream` a better approach could be to check the return value of `[oStream write:]`: if it returns -1 no data has been sent, so there's no connection.

However, if you want to wait two seconds you can use [NSTimer](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/&ei=6zQsTtPqFsHrOfWg0eQK&usg=AFQjCNEMUXK2xYIGDSqH4ld_p6133ffj9Q&sig2=vg0WZtNRSSElPO3fzpMH8w) to create a timeout. If you receive a response before the timer fires you can invalidate the timer, otherwise the timer will call the related method that will notify the end of the two seconds.

Comment: when I found out that [oStream write:] returned and int I thought that maybe that was the solution. But if I try to run that when providing an incorrect ip address for some reason it does not return anything. it just wait's there. I'll keep trying...

Comment: How long did you wait? If I provide a wrong IP it takes a while, but at the end it returns -1...

Comment: yeah but it my case I don't know why it takes forever. I tried waiting two minutes and the app is till frozen when I reach: [oStream write:buf maxLength:strlen((char*)buf)];    thanks a lot for the help Saphrosit

Comment: Well, that's definitely strange. Have you tried to check `[oStream streamStatus]` or `[oStream streamError]`?

Comment: Is there a way I can terminate that process? I am new to objective-c but in other languages I would run that in a separate threat and the set an timer and when the timer finishes if that method is still running I would terminate it.

Comment: I ran that method in a separate thread using what you mention and everything worked out great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try pausing the main run loop.

```
- (void)test
{
    NSLog(@"Test starting.");

    BOOL wasSuccessful = [self connect];
    NSLog(@"Success: %d", wasSuccessful);
}

- (BOOL)connect
{
    // try to connect here, make sure to get a callback on success/failure

    // fake callback
    [self performSelector:@selector(callback:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] afterDelay:2.0];

    // wait for callback
    CFRunLoopRun();
    return self.success;
}

- (void)callback:(NSNumber *)successful
{
    self.success = [successful boolValue];

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()); // now we want -connect to return!
}
```